# The type org.apache.camel.impl.HeaderFilterStrategyComponent cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I faced following problem on my camel application:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for 
>   org.apache.camel.impl.HeaderFilterStrategyComponent. Fix the build
>   path then try building this project    camel

```
public class SendMessageToActiveMq {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(factory));
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
}
```

Here is my maven pom dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Note:**
It does work with camel-core 2.24.2. Why it is not working with 3.0.0? What is the alternative?

Comment: Are you sure that ```HeaderFilterStrategyComponent``` is present in camel-core 3.0.0? Looking through the document I can't find the class

Comment: @D.Lawrence, If not present then what is the alternative?

Comment: @D.Lawrence, It does work with camel-core 2.24.2. Why it is not working 3.0.0?

Comment: I couldn't say :( Maybe they failed their release and the 3.0.0 isn't usable.

Comment: how did you resolve this? I am still getting same error even when I list dependency as activemq-camel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Camel 3 [migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_activemq). The activemq-camel component was moved to the Apache Camel codebase. Update your dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class has been moved and you need to update your import statement:

```
import org.apache.camel.support.HeaderFilterStrategyComponent;
```

You can find the class [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/HeaderFilterStrategyComponent.java).